# Can the here maps API access the send-to-car feature?

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to automate sending locations to my car via the wego.here.com maps API.
The feature is there in the web page but I'm struggling to find it anywhere in the API documentation. Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a link for the documentation here: https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks

Comment: Thanks, that doens't seem quite right as the send-to-car function isn't included in the official Here mobile app, only on the web version. I'll have another look through though.